# how to include WordPress wp-config.php to gain access to the MySQL DB info

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a project for users with WP installed domains.

I store data in the same DB that WP uses (just in different tables).

I cant use the include function to fetch the file and simply use the info from there because, according to a user from `http://wordpress.stackexchange.com`, the `wp-config.php` should never be included in a file after posting a question regarding issues I was encountering (only **sometimes**) when doing so ([The Issues that encounter when including the file](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/40140/being-redirected-to-install-php-wordpress-is-already-installed-when-includin)).

Now, I already have one option (because inculding the wp-config.php issues *ONLY* encounter **sometimes**):

The application I'm working on requires an installation to run (by the user). So, during that installation, I could just simply include the `wp-config.php` file **ONCE**, copy the info I need, and place it into my own file, and just use that for the rest of the application.

The issue with the solution above is, what if i encounter the issues during the installation? The user would have to try again and again until it works. = un-happy user.

Any ideas on alternatives I could use to acomplish this?

Comment: there is a way to get the wpdb access from a standalone script, once I remember how I'll share the answer.

Comment: @thenetimp: I need the DB info (host,user,pass). I dont want to access the DB through WP functions. Thanks.

Comment: If you use my answer below you still have access to the all the constants. that contain that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This blog post](http://www.markflint.net/parsing-wordpress-wp-config-php-file/) seems to have the answer you're looking for, complete with code to do it.  The author does as is suggested in the comments of the post you linked in your question.

Excerpt from the post:

> I need a script to extract the database details from the wp-config.php
>   file so I could keep the logon details in one location when I was
>   coding something outside the WP framework.
>
> I came up with a class that does this, connects to mysql and selects
>   the database. There are three connection options: `PDO`, `mySQLi` or the
>   procedural `mysql_connect()`.

**UPDATE**: As original blog post is unavailable here's the original code:

```
<?php
/**
 * This class pulls the database logon information out of wp-config.
 * It then evals the settings it finds into PHP and then makes the
 * database connection.
 *
 * Acts as a Singleton.
 *
 * @package wpConfigConnection
 * @author Mark Flint
 * @link www.bluecubeinteractive.com
 * @copyright Please just leave this PHPDoc header in place.
 */
Class wpConfigConnection
  {
  /**
   * @var object $_singleton This is either null in the case that this class has not been
   * called yet, or an instance of the class object if the class has been called.
   *
   * @access public
   */
  private static $_singleton;
  /**
   * @var resource $_con The connection.
   * @access public
   */
  public $_con;

  /**
   * The wp-config.php file var
   * @var string $str The string that the file is brought into.
   * @access private
   */
  private $str;
  /**
   * @var $filePath Path to wp-config.php file
   * @access private
   */
  private $filePath;
  /**
   * @var array Array of constant names used by wp-config.php for the
   * logon details
   * @access private
   */
  private $paramA = array(
    'DB_NAME',
    'DB_USER',
    'DB_PASSWORD',
    'DB_HOST'
  );
  /**
   * @var bool $database Can check this var to see if your database was connected successfully
   */
  public $_database;

  /**
   * Constructor. This function pulls everything together and makes it happen.
   * This could be unraveled to make the whole thing more flexible later.
   *
   * @param string $filePath Path to wp-config.php file
   * @access private
   */
  private
  function __construct($type = 1, $filePath = './wp-config.php')
    {
    $this->filePath = $filePath;
    $this->getFile();
    $this->serverBasedCondition();
    /**
     * eval the WP contants into PHP
     */
    foreach($this->paramA as $p)
      {
      $this->evalParam('define(\'' . $p . '\'', '\');');
      }

    switch ($type)
      {
    default:
    case 1:
      $this->conMySQL_Connect();
      break;

    case 2:
      $this->conPDO();
      break;

    case 3:
      $this->conMySQLi();
      break;
      }
    }

  /**
   * Make the connection using mysql_connect
   */
  private
  function conMySQL_Connect()
    {
    try
      {
      if (($this->_con = @mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD)) == false)
        {
        throw new Exception('Could not connect to mySQL. ' . mysql_error());
        }
      }

    catch(Exception $e)
      {
      exit('Error on line  ' . $e->getLine() . ' in ' . $e->getFile() . ': ' . $e->getMessage());
      }

    try
      {
      if (($this->_database = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $this->_con)) == false)
        {
        throw new Exception('Could not select database. ' . mysql_error());
        }
      }

    catch(Exception $e)
      {
      exit('Error on line  ' . $e->getLine() . ' in ' . $e->getFile() . ': ' . $e->getMessage());
      }
    }

  /**
   * Make the connection using mySQLi
   */
  private
  function conMySQLi()
    {
    $this->_con = @new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      exit('MySQLi connection failed: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
      }
    }

  /**
   * Make the connection using PDO
   */
  private
  function conPDO()
    {
    try
      {
      $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME;
      $this->_con = @new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
      }

    catch(PDOException $e)
      {
      exit('Error on line  ' . $e->getLine() . ' in ' . $e->getFile() . ': ' . $e->getMessage());
      }
    }

  /**
   * Read the wp-config.php file into a string
   *
   * @access private
   */
  private
  function getFile()
    {
    try
      {
      $this->str = @file_get_contents($this->filePath);
      if ($this->str == false)
        {
        throw new Exception('Failed to read file (' . $this->filePath . ') into string.');
        }
      }

    catch(Exception $e)
      {
      exit('Error on line  ' . $e->getLine() . ' in ' . $e->getFile() . ': ' . $e->getMessage());
      }
    }

  /**
   * Get the logon parameter and evaluate it into PHP.
   * Eg, eval("define('DB_NAME', 'm4j3lub3_wordpress');");
   *
   * @param string $pre This defines what to look for at the start of a logon parameter
   * definition. Eg, if you are looking for  "define('DB_NAME', 'm4j3lub3_wordpress');"
   * then the $pre bit would be "define('DB_NAME'".
   *
   * @param string $post Like $pre, this defines what to look for at the end of the logon
   * parameter definition. In the case of WordPress it is always going to be "');"
   *
   * @access private
   */
  private
  function evalParam($pre, $post)
    {
    $str = $this->str;
    $str1 = substr($str, strpos($str, $pre));
    $str1 = substr($str1, 0, strpos($str1, $post) + strlen($post));
    eval($str1);
    }

  /**
   * Grab the right code block if there are more than one set of definitions
   *
   * Sets $this->str to be the right code block
   *
   * Used for when there are conditional settings based on local or remote configuration,
   * using the condition: if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=='localhost') { ...
   *
   * @access private
   */
  private
  function serverBasedCondition()
    {
    if (strpos($this->str, '$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]') || strpos($this->str, '$_SERVER[\'HTTP_HOST\']'))
      {
      if (strpos($this->str, '$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]'))
        {

        // case of double quotes - get a substring

        $this->str = substr($this->str, strpos($this->str, '$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]'));
        }
      elseif (strpos($this->str, '$_SERVER[\'HTTP_HOST\']'))
        {

        // case of single quotes - get a substring

        $this->str = substr($this->str, strpos($this->str, '$_SERVER[\'HTTP_HOST\']'));
        }

      // substring from 1st occurance of {

      $this->str = substr($this->str, strpos($this->str, '{') + 1);
      if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'local.dev')
        {

        // local - substring from start to 1st occurance of } - this is now the block

        $this->str = substr($this->str, 0, strpos($this->str, '}') - 1);
        }
        else
        {

        // remote - substring from the else condition

        $this->str = substr($this->str, strpos($this->str, '{') + 1);
        $this->str = substr($this->str, 0, strpos($this->str, '}') - 1);
        }

      // replace all double quote with single to make it easier to find the param definitions

      $this->str = str_replace('"', '\'', $this->str);
      }
    }

  /**
   * Return an instance of the class based on type of connection passed
   *
   * $types are:
   * 1 = Procedural connection using mysql_connect()
   * 2 = OOP connection using PHP Data Objects (PDO)
   * 3 = OOP connection using mySQLi
   *
   * @return resource Database connection
   * @access private
   */
  private static
  function returnInstance($type)
    {
    if (is_null(self::$_singleton))
      {
      self::$_singleton = new wpConfigConnection($type);
      }

    return self::$_singleton;
    }

  /**
   * Action the return of the instance based on Procedural connection using mysql_connect()
   *
   * @access public
   * @return resource Procedural connection using mysql_connect()
   */
  public static

  function getInstance()
    {
    return self::returnInstance(1);
    }

  /**
   * Action the return of the instance based on OOP connection using PDO
   *
   * @access public
   * @return resource OOP connection using PHP Data Objects (PDO)
   */
  public static

  function getPDOInstance()
    {
    return self::returnInstance(2);
    }

  /**
   * Action the return of the instance based on OOP connection using mySQLi
   *
   * @access public
   * @return resource OOP connection using mySQLi
   */
  public static

  function getMySQLiInstance()
    {
    return self::returnInstance(3);
    }
  }

// USAGE EXAMPLES
// mysql_connect example

$mfdb = wpConfigConnection::getInstance();
try
  {
  $query = 'select * FROM wp_users';
  $res = mysql_query($query);
  if ($res == false)
    {
    throw new Exception('mySQL error: ' . mysql_error() . '. Query: ' . $query);
    }
  }

catch(Exception $e)
  {
  echo 'Error on line  ' . $e->getLine() . ' in ' . $e->getFile() . ': ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
  }

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
  {
  echo $row['user_login'] . '<br />';
  }

// PDO example, showing prepared statement with bound value

$mfdb = wpConfigConnection::getPDOInstance();
$mfdb->_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);
$mfdb->_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$query = "SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE 1=:cond";
$stmt = $mfdb->_con->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(':cond', 1);
$stmt->execute();

while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
  {
  echo $row['user_login'] . '<br />';
  }

$mfdb->_con = null;

// mySQLi example

$mfdb = wpConfigConnection::getMySQLiInstance();
$sql = ' SELECT * FROM wp_users';

if (!$mfdb->_con->real_query($sql))
  {
  echo 'Error in query: ' . $mfdb->_con->error;
  exit;
  }

if ($result = $mfdb->_con->store_result())
  {
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
    echo $row['user_login'] . '<br />';
    }
  }

$result->close();
?>
```

Source: https://web.archive.org/web/20130410000149/www.markflint.net/parsing-wordpress-wp-config-php-file/

Comment: Link to article has been deleted.

Comment: @AbijeetPatro Fixed, the author apparently changed a setting on his blog.

Answer (score 1):

For projects that had to integrate with an installation of WordPress I always included 'wp-blog-header.php'.

[Integrating WordPress with Your Website](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website)

example:

```
<?php 
/* Short and sweet */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```

After reading the comments, I would suggest writing (in the installation process) a script that looks for the config file for WordPress and pulls out the defined values for DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_HOST, DB_CHARSET, DB_COLLATE and stores them in your own configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest creating a file called page-custom-name.php in your theme folder, and publish an empty page with the exact title "Custom-name". Now when you'll be visiting www.yoursite/custom-name you will see that page.

And in page-custom-name.php you just type:

```
global $wpdb;
```

and you have acces to the database :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

require_once('wp-load.php');

// your script here. which conforms to wordpress standards.
```

Comment: Tried that. I encounter the same issues, as when including `wp-config.php`.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want access to wp-config.php without the rest of the Wordpress functions.

Do the following steps:

1: create a empty wp-settings.php file in your plugin directory

2: ad this to your php file

```
define( 'ABSPATH', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-content/plugins/YOUR_PLUGIN_DIR/' ); require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-config.php' );
```

This works perfect for WordPress 4.2.4 "down and up" and I tested it in our own plugin mywebapplets.

Comment: Use caution, because you're not guaranteed to find plugins in `/wp-content/plugins` -- some security plugins change the location of `/wp-content` to something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variant of Soner Gönül solution, also based on a stand-alone script. Be careful to put this file in a place where nobody can access it, except you (example: an Apache password protected folder, or another domain with restrictions of access). Do the following steps:

1 - create an empty php script called wp-settings.php

2 - assuming that the path to your WordPress folder is /var/www/html/, add the code below to another script (example: db-info.php), placed in the same folder as the empty script created formerly.

```
<?php
// you are defining ABSPATH here, so wp-config.php won't be able to define it again. The result is that wp-config.php, when required, will require your empty script (and not the real wp-settings.php), avoiding this way the start of WordPress loading.
define('ABSPATH', __DIR__ . '/');
// assuming that the path to your WordPress folder is /var/www/html/. Typing the path directly, instead of using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], will allow you to run the script from anywhere (another domain of your server, for example).
require_once '/var/www/html/wp-config.php';
```

3 - To see the code working: add the following lines to the end of your script,

```
echo DB_NAME . '<br>';
echo DB_HOST . '<br>';
```

and test it with your browser, accessing: http://'one-of-your-domains/path-to/db-info.php